# C# masked textbox validation WITHOUT REGEX

Tags: c#, validation, phone-number, zipcode, maskedtextbox

I'm working on a class assignment that has us writing an ordering application for a tea company. The assignment requires us to validate user input.

I'm using a masked textbox control for the state abbreviation, telephone number, and ZIP+4 code. I specified LL for the state abbreviation in the mask (BTW, I would like to validate that using a (pardon me) "if string is AK || AL || etc" check if possible), so there's no way to enter anything but letters. However, for the ZIP code, I had to trucate to five digits in my textbox, because trying to parse the field to int always fails (I think because of the hyphen). I'm having similar problems with the telephone number.

SO, my question is this:

How do I validate user data in a masked text box when the mask itself includes (, ), and - ? These characters seem to be getting included in the check, which is not what I want.

Also, I do not want regex solutions. We haven't covered those in class yet, and I want to stick with things I understand. We have covered try/catch, tryparse, and switch cases, but none of those seem appropriate for this problem.

Code:

```
private void CastAndValidateInput()
    {

        validInputBoolean = false;

        if (vendorNameTextBox.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
        {

            if (vendorContactTextBox.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
            {

                if (streetAddressTextBox.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
                {

                    if (cityTextBox.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
                    {

                        if (stateMaskedTextBox.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
                        {

                            if (zipCodeMaskedTextBox.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
                            {

                                try // this works... if I use 5-digit ZIP code
                                {

                                    zipCodeAsInteger = int.Parse(zipCodeMaskedTextBox.Text);

                                    try // this still does not work, presumably because of the mask's special characters
                                    {

                                        telephoneNumberAsInteger = UInt32.Parse(telephoneNumberMaskedTextBox.Text);

                                        try
                                        {

                                            quantityInteger = int.Parse(quantityTextBox.Text);
                                            validInputBoolean = true;

                                        }

                                        catch
                                        {

                                            MessageBox.Show("You must enter a quantity as a whole number.", "INVALID QUANTITY ENTERED", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                                            quantityTextBox.Focus();
                                            quantityTextBox.SelectAll();

                                        }

                                    }

                                    catch
                                    {

                                        MessageBox.Show("This does not appear to be a valid telelphone number. Please enter only digits, and do not use separators such as (, ), or -.", "INVALID TELEPHONE NUMBER", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                                        telephoneNumberMaskedTextBox.Focus();
                                        telephoneNumberMaskedTextBox.SelectAll();

                                    }

                                }

                                catch
                                {

                                    MessageBox.Show("You have entered an invalid value as a ZIP code. Please re-enter your ZIP+4 code in the indicated entry field.", "INVALID ZIP CODE", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                                    zipCodeMaskedTextBox.Focus();
                                    zipCodeMaskedTextBox.SelectAll();


                                }

                            }

                            else // the format for the mask is 00000-9999 but the hyphen seems to be a problem for the checks I know how to do
                            {

                                MessageBox.Show("You must enter a ZIP+4 code.", "ZIP+4 NOT ENTERED", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                                zipCodeMaskedTextBox.Focus();

                            }

                        }

                        else // this can be validated with a simple 'string equal to this || this || this' statement (right??)
                        {

                            MessageBox.Show("You must enter a state abbreviation.", "STATE ABBREVIATION NOT ENTERED", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                            stateMaskedTextBox.Focus();

                        }

                    }

                    else
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("You must enter a city.", "CITY NOT ENTERED", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                        cityTextBox.Focus();

                    }

                }

                else 
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("You must enter a street address.", "STREET ADDRESS NOT ENTERED", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                    streetAddressTextBox.Focus();

                }

            }

            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("You must enter a vendor contact name.", "VENDOR CONTACT NAME NOT ENTERED", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                vendorContactTextBox.Focus();

            }

        }

        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("You must enter a vendor name.", "VENDOR NAME NOT ENTERED", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

            vendorNameTextBox.Focus();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Deeply nested if statements like that are hard to follow.  Why don't you validate one text box at a time, re-using the validation logic where appropriate?

Comment: Since the hyphen and parenthesis are included in the text (yes), you can call methods like `String.SubString`/`String.Replace` to get rid of them before checking.

Comment: This is how we did it in class and I am trying very hard to not do anything differently where possible.